# What components make VIM a good (great) ruby editor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

I'm learning **ruby on rails** on a **linux** box and dusting off my **VIM** skills (skillz?).

[image]

When I got started on VIM way back in my c++ days, I had a friend with a great vimfiles folder that had tons of stuff to get started.  Starting from scratch, vim is great, but it feels like it could be a lot better.

I currently have:

- [vim-ruby](http://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby)
- [buffer explorer](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=42)
- [xml-edit](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=301) (though I don't have it currently working with erb files)

I know that barely scratches the surface of what some more experienced vim/ruby devs have (including the one offs in the vim.rc file).

Is there a list somewhere (or could we create one) of a bunch of the standard vim configurations needed to make programming ruby (and rails) more fun?  Is there a zip/tarball somewhere with a good base setup?

Comment: This repo is more macvim oriented but there's a lot of plugins listed that can help http://github.com/carlhuda/janus

Comment: +1 just because I like the Vim Ruby icon. =p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

take a look at tim pope's repos on git hub. Many, many awesome vim plugins and extensions for working with ruby and rails

http://github.com/tpope

Answer (score 2):

[snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) ([GitHub repo](http://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim)) is highly recommended. It enables you to use TextMate-style snippets in Vim.

snipMate is not Ruby-specific: by default, it comes with one file containing Ruby-specific snippets. If you are going to work a lot on Ruby-based code (*Rails, RSpec, Shoulda, and the like*), it's probably better to use one of the [available](http://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets) [snippets'](http://github.com/kaichen/vim-snipmate-ruby-snippets) [collections](http://github.com/travisjeffery/snipmate-snippets) and customize it as you see fit rather than writing your own snippets from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty nice setup for your VIM environment.

http://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles

Just follow the instructions and in a minute or two you will have everything ready for Ruby(on Rails) development.

As Jed has mentioned above - tpope plugin is a "must have" and it is part of the akita vimfiles.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my `~/.vimrc` to quickly see the output of a file I'm working on:

```
map <Leader>r :w! <bar> !ruby %<CR>
```

For rails, two essential plugins are [rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) and [the NERD tree,](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) for navigating the directory of the rails project you're working on.

Comment: I have a more advanced version of that: https://github.com/henrik/dotfiles/blob/85bec7e782e4fd31e940438a0fff88aef2b1f358/vimrc#L217-260 Will probably roll it into a plugin at some point.